# How to desgin class relation. Should they know abouth themselves?

Tags: vb.net, oop, architecture

This is all done in vb.net

I hava a class "INVOICE" and a class "SHIPMENT"

Invoice class has a SHIPMENTS property (list of shipment class), so I can write code like this:

```
dim inv as new Invoice
dim ship as new Shipment
inv.shipments.add(ship)
```

Now shipment class can exist without the invoice class. It is used in other parts of the application where it does not "belong" to any invoice.

Now on many occasions I find myself in a need to reference the INVOICE of the shipment that I am for example passing as a parameter.
I want to write for example:

```
Private Sub SetUpLabels(ship as Shipment)
    lblInvoice.Text = ship.Invoice.Number
    lblShipmentDestination.Text = ship.Destination
End Sub
```

What is a proper way of achieving my goal?

I have a feeling I shouldnt be adding INVOICE as a property of SHIPMENT class
Should I be passing both the INVOICE and SHIPMENT as a parameter in this case
Something like this?

```
Private Sub SetUpLabels(ship as Shipment, inv as Invoice)
    lblInvoice.Text = inv.Number
    lblShipmentDestination.Text = ship.Destination
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you familiar with UML class diagrams?

Comment: Yes. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can a `Shipment` be associated with one or no `Invoices`s or, could a `Shipment` be associated with many `Invoice`s?

Comment: The first option. 'Shipment' can be associated with one or no 'Inovices'.

Comment: @GlutVonSmark I can't immediately think of the _why_ behind implementing associations like this, but I know that you shouldn't try to decouple classes that have this sort of mutual dependency. I'll let you know if I can think of a sensible reason.

Comment: What to you mean by saying that: "you shouldn't try to decouple classes that have this sort of mutual dependency".

Comment: The shipments that _do_ belong to an invoice should know about their invoice. Consider this the equivalent of having a printed copy of the invoice inside the box. Likewise, the printed invoice would probably list the date and number of the shipment. There is a mutual dependency that you shouldn't break. My class diagram shows you how to implement it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you were already doing things properly. You might want to take it one step further, and design a class `InvoiceShipment` that extends `Shipment` with a property of type `Invoice`.

```
dim inv as new Invoice

dim ship as new InvoiceShipment

inv.shipments.add(ship) 

ship.Invoice = inv
```

[image: class diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other options, additionally to Steven Liekens answer.

Use some kind of Decorator for the `InvoiceShipment`:

```
Class InvoiceShipment
    Public Property DecoratedShipment As Shipment 
    Public Property Invoice As Invoice
End Class
```

And then

```
Class Invoice
    Private shipments As List(Of InvoiceShipment)
    Public Sub AddShipment(s As Shipment)
        shipments.Add(New InvoiceShipment With {.Invoice = Me, .DecoratedShipment = s})
    End Sub

    'If you just need the plain invoices
    Iterator Function GetShipments() As IEnumerable(Of Shipment)
        For Each s As InvoiceShipment In shipments
            Yield s.DecoratedShipment
        Next
     End Function
```

Another way is to use extension methods:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module ShipmentExtensions

    Dim invoiceMapping As New ConditionalWeakTable(Of Shipment, Invoice)

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetInvoice(ByVal shipment As Shipment) As Invoice
        Dim invoice As Invoice
        If Not invoiceMapping.TryGetValue(shipment, invoice) Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Return invoice
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub SetInvoice(shipment As Shipment, invoice As Invoice)
        invoiceMapping.Add(shipment, invoice)        
    End Sub

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub UnsetInvoice(shipment As Shipment)
        invoiceMapping.Remove(shipment)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then in the `Invoice` class you just need to set the invoice:

```
Class Invoice 
   ...
   Public Sub AddShipment(ByVal shipment As Shipment)
       ...
       shipment.SetInvoice(Me)
   End Sub
```

And you can access the invoice whereever you need via `anyShipment.GetInvoice()`. Be aware that this might return `Nothing` if no `Invoice` is associated.

This method is some kind of mixin that realizes the fact that a shipment might play the role `ShipmentInInvoice`. But modelling dynamic roles is quite hard. Therefore, this is a static role.